# Set height of Fullcalendar.io events in a resourceTimeline

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

i want to set the height of my events, so they fill the full blank space of their time slot.
Events should completely occupy the shaded space. There is always only one event in a time slot.
My resources are on the y-axis and the time is displayed on the x-axis.

I tried `eventMinHeight: 25`, but this only works for TimeGrid views.

[A fullcalendar with one resource event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh9Xu.png)

Does anyone know how to to that?

Comment: You can probably make a CSS rule to do it

Comment: Thankyou @ADyson it worked. I also needed to overwrite an inline style with square brackets and !important. Maybe this will also help someone in the future.

Comment: If you found a solution, please add it as an Answer below, otherwise it will not help anyone in future because they won't be able to find it (because to the search engines, this question appears to be un-answered. The solution is not part of the question!). And also you can get separate upvotes on your answer(s) rather than your questions. See also the [tour] if you're unsure how the structure of Stackoverflow works, and also [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to overwrite an inline style with square brackets and !important.

```html
.fc-event-container[style] {
   height: 59% !important;
}

.fc-event[style] {
   height: 100% !important;
}
```

Thanks for your help in the comments @ADyson.